# How many mixed double pairs can be made from 7 married couples provided that no husband and wife plays in a same set?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So for first man there can be 7 possible partners including his wife, for the next man there will be 6 possible partners and so on,

therefore for $7$ men and $7$ women, there will be $7!$ possible pairs.

that is $5040$

There can be only $7$ possible pairs in which all married couples can pair up.(one for each couple)

therefore the answer is $5040$ - $7$ = $5033$

EDIT:- ok i got it this is wrong.
So for the correct answer i have to choose 4 men and 4 women such that none of them is related to one another ? Right ?

Comment: No.  The problem disallows ANY married couple from teaming up, you only handle the case in which EVERY married couple teams up.  To address the question, look up [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: No there are 2940 ways

Comment: So i have to choose 4 men and 4 women such that none of them is related to one another ? Right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose $2$ men for set: $\binom72 = 21$ ways

Choose $2$ women who are not their spouses for their partners: $\binom52= 10$ ways

There can now be only $2$ possible pairs: $M_1W_1-M_2W_2\;\; or\;\; M_1W_2-M_2W_1$

Thus number of possible pairs under the given conditions $=21*10*2 = 420$

Comment: Please, write all pairs for 4 couples(or for 3 at least)

Comment: @Mr. Newman: Ac-Bd, Ad-Bc, Ab-Cd, Ad-Cb, Ab-Dc, Ac-Db, you should be able to continue.....

Comment: @Mr. Newman: btw, with $3$ couples, you can't have a valid pairing !

Answer (score -1):

One of the male players has $7$ women he can choose
as a partner, minus his wife $ = 6$

The number of possible pairs is $7\times6$

The other male player is one of the $6$ remaining, and he can choose one of $6$ remaining women, minus his wife $= 5$

The number of possible pairs is $6\times5$.

The number of possible matches is $7\times6\times6\times5 = 1260$

Comment: Please, make comment here, if you have found this wrong explanation.

Answer (score -1):

We have the recurrence relation $a_n=(n-1)a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-2},a_1=0,a_2=1$ and we want $a_7$. We easily calculate 1, 2, 9, 44, 265, 1854.

To see the recurrence relation. Suppose $n$ picks $k$. There are two cases: $k$ does not pick $n$ and $k$ does pick $n$.

Answer (score -1):

It' s a ["derangement"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) problem. In the general case for $n$ couples the answer is a subfactorial of $n$
$$!n = n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
So if $n=7$ the answer is 1854